# How to attach file using Rest api Java?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, java

Can some budyy help me out. How to upload attachment using Rest 
[REST API Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm?search_text=attachment)

I am following this link.

Is there any sample code available?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any custom REST API or any standard one?

Comment: I have Setup REST Environment in Java.

Comment: I think you will have to pass Blob data to Java app. Check whether you can have Blob variable inside HTTPRequest or not.